# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException error in Mule soft 3.7.3 Failed to read schema mule- secure-property-placeholder

Tags: java, xml, mule, anypoint-studio

My Mule project in anypoint studio was working fine yesterday, now I am getting this error

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read
>   schema document
>   'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder/current/mule-
>   secure-property-placeholder.xsd', because 1) could not find the
>   document; 2) the  document could not be read; 3) the root element of
>   the document is not xsd:schema.

I update all the available updates including secure-property-placeholder, but no luck.

Comment: Check if this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281459/mule-how-can-project-configs-cause-such-misleading-sax-errors) is of any use.

Comment: Did you find the solution?